# Bootstrap create active buttons link in header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I'm learning bootstrap/CSS while I design a website for a course.

[Heroku app](https://fierce-brushlands-63385.herokuapp.com)

Right now I have my header which is fine. There are some buttons, which have a  tag which covers all of them and that's all inside some divs and containers.

I want it so that when I click Home or whatever button is active, I can change its color, grey for example while I'm on that part of the site. I tried &:active but it doesn't work that way.

Sorry if it's been asked before I have searched a lot and don't know how to find it. Also checked bootstrap docs.

Heres's my code

```
CSS

header{
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 0em;
}

.navbar-inverse{
background: gray;
}



.btn {
border-style: dotted;
border-color: gray;
line-height: 5em;
width: 8em;


a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;




    &:active{
        background-color: gray;
    }


    &:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: navy;
    }

    }
}

.btn-lg{
background: black;
height: 90px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


HTML HEADER

<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">

<button type="button "class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "Log Out", root_path %></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "New Event", new_event_path %></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "All Events", events_path %></button>


</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a jquery that will set the button to be active or not. See below code for reference.

HTML:

```
 <a href='#' class='btn btn-default'>
Link 1</a>

<a href='#' class='btn btn-default'>
Link 2</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: This could be it. I've already implemented it but I don't know where should I add the .active class. Do I add it to the buttons, to .btn class, to the links?

Comment: Yes,  you can do it.  You can also just leave it as it is. The button here in the jquery selector points to the button element.

Comment: Or try replacing your buttons to anchor tags then replace the jquery selctor to 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, give `class` name to your button , suppose man, then in ur css `.man:active` give it color u want.

```
.man:active{
background-color: #2222;
}
```

and now if u want that after u click a button, the color should remain the same,
which ever button has been visited,

```
.man:visited{
background-color: #ffff;
}
```

Comment: Visited works fine. The problem is that if I go to another tab then the visited tab doesn't refresh to its original state. The color keeps being the same so that doesn't work for me.